# Ionic multi level push side menu navigation issue

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

i want to make multi level push side menu in the ionic 1 app, like [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eCKkm) .
In my ionic app I have three ion-nav-view:
1.One in the index.html ""
2.Two in the menu:

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
<ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar>
        <ion-nav-back-button>
        </ion-nav-back-button>

        <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
            <button class="button button-icon button-clear burger-vok 
              ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
            </button>
        </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-side-menu-content>

<ion-side-menu side="left" class="sidemenu dark-bg vok-bg">
    <ion-nav-bar>
        <ion-nav-back-button>
        </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>

    <ion-nav-view name="sideView"></ion-nav-view>

</ion-side-menu>
```

in the Routing config.:

```
.state('app', {
                url: '/app',
                abstract: true,
                templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html'
  })
  .state('app.main-menu', {
                url: "/mainmenu",
                views: {
                    'sideView': {
                        templateUrl: 'templates/main-menu.html',
                        controller: 'MenuCtrl'
                    }
                }
            })

            .state('app.sidemenu', {
                url: "/submenu/:id",
                views: {
                    'sideView': {
                        templateUrl: 'templates/sub-menu.html',
                        controller: 'SubmenuCtrl'
                    }
                }
            })

            .state('app.start', {
                url: '/start',
                views: {
                    'menuContent': {
                        templateUrl: 'templates/start.html',
                        controller: 'StartCtrl'
                    },
                    'sideView': {
                        templateUrl: 'templates/main-menu.html',
                        controller: 'MenuCtrl'
                    }

                }
            })
        .
        .
        .
```

but when I run the app, no nav-bar appears at all in both views!
What i'm missing hier ?